# Publishing to FTP Works - Cannot Install using URL from Website

Tags: visual-studio, ftp, web, clickonce, publish

### Goal

I want to publish my WinForm application to my FTP. I then want to send the appropriate link to my users who will be able to update this application via website.

---

### Publish Tab

Take a look at my publish tab below. 
[image: Visual Studio Publish Tab]

I can successfully publish to my FTP site.
[image: Success On Publish]

---

The issue now is I cannot install the application using the installation folder URL. Previously, using a network file path, I could send a hyperlink such as: \progs\TestApp\setup.exe

How do I go about installing the application using a website URL provided in my Installation Folder URL found in the publish tab?

Answer (score 0):

Ok figured it out ... My  bad.

**Publishing folder location**

ftp://mywebsite.com/public_html/test/

**Installation folder**

http://mywebsite.com/test/

---

That fixed my issues since my users can now install it using http://mywebsite.com/test/setup.exe

Comment: Can you explain regarding how did you get that URL installation path?

Comment: @sivaram After searching and testing, I saw the installation folder was a different URL than the publishing folder location on several examples. Tested it out and it worked... Not quite sure why

Comment: Ok That's great. But where did you find out the URL?

Comment: @sivaram The URL in my answer was an example. My actual URL was gotten from a domain that I purchased but I didn't divulged that URL publicly